# Expatriates proposal is into the Commitment stage, signups needed!

Tags: discussion, immigration-questions, expat-questions

We've had a lot of debate, both recently and over the years, on what to do with Immigration and Expat style questions. As part of that, people were originally suggested to support the Immigration proposal, which sadly failed to get momentum. Since then, the suggestion was the [Expatriates](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732?phase=commitment) proposal, which has now made it to the [commitment stage!](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732?phase=commitment)

I would encourage everyone, whichever side of the debate they come down on, to sign up to support the [proposal now](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732?phase=commitment).

(If you believe that immigration and expat questions are best served elsewhere, then having a running site is the best way to have them asked on Travel. If you believe they could live in Travel, then having a site to try would be in your interest to, as if it didn't work in beta you would at least have that as a strong reason why to push for them in Travel!)

So, whichever side you sit on, please head to the [Expat proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732?phase=commitment), create an account if you haven't already got one (it'll be auto-linked to your others), and commit!

Comment: I suggest every Travel.SE member which commits to Expatriates proposal should upvote that topic, to sent signal to the others. We need 200 people overall!

Comment: A thousand times yes.

Comment: Is it possible to add a temporary banner on the main site to let people know about it?

Comment: @Gagravarr I think we can use [community promotion ads](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/community-promotion-ads-2013)

Comment: The proposal seems to be doing quite well for 200+ rep users, with 53 of the required 100 signed up. The big thing needed is more "normal" new users, so it's time to start letting your friends / family members / hostel mates know to sign up and join in!